# Расшифровка байтового массива на Node.js

Tags: node.js, javascript

Пишу на Node.js серверную часть для GPS-трекера Teltonika FM1100. Возникла проблема с расшифровкой полученного двоичного AVL-пакета с информацией о местоположении трекера и состоянии I/O-устройств.Полученный пакет привожу ниже:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 03 b9 08 19 00 00 01 3b 10 13 9f a6 00 17 fb 34 60 1c 74 37 20 00 89 00 00 08 00 00 00 03 01 45 01 02 b6 00 0c 42 2f c8 00 00 00 00 01
```

Согласно документации по протоколу AVL Novacom GNS Extended первым байтом должен идти идентификатор кодека 08,но вместо этого у меня в начале куча нулевых байтов.Подскажите как расшифровать данный пакет

Comment: Значит вам удалось передать двоичное 01? А то Вы не ответили в предыдущем вашем вопросе.

Comment: Да,удалось передать 01. Как я и предполагал ошибка была в строке socket.write(0x01). Вместо нее я написал:

   var buf=new Buffer(1);
   buf.writeUInt8(0x01,0);
   
После чего записал данный буфер в сокет и трекер ответил)

Answer (score 1):

Всё,разобрался,может кому пригодится. Пишем функцию

```
function hexToDec(hex){return parseInt(hex,16);}
```

В нее передаем либо единичный байт, либо набор байтов, но в таком случае в виде строки обрамленной кавычками. На выходе получаем какое либо целочисленное  значение (широта,долгота,скорость и т.д.).Вот собственно и всё